# Issue getting the IDs of trending news videos on YouTube?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I've been trying to get trending news videos from the United States using the YouTube Data API. However, while I have not received an error, I have not received any results. I find it very hard to believe that there are no results because YouTube's trending news page shows many videos.

What I get back:

```
{'kind': 'youtube#videoListResponse', 'etag': 'KtFSnIG_fmDzS9uX1a7JuXFZJbk', 'items': [], 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 0, 'resultsPerPage': 5}}
```

My code:

```
youtube = build("youtube","v3", developerKey=apiKey)

  
request = youtube.videos().list(
    part = "id",
    chart = "mostPopular",
    regionCode = "US",
    videoCategoryId = "25"
)

response = request.execute()

print(response)
```

Comment: I confirm replicating your issue. Removing `videoCategoryId` or changing it to `10`, I did obtained a list of video IDs. I'd recommend to file a bug report directly to Google through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: @stvar Ok, I will file a big report

Comment: [Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178904645) is the link to the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see how you do.

```
result = self.youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet",
        regionCode="US",
        videoCategoryId = 25,
        order="viewCount",
        type="video",
    ).execute()

    for item in result['items']:
        print()
        print(item["id"]["videoId"])
    return result
```

All the best.

Comment: That doesnt work. I dont get YouTube's trending news.